# Declaration and assignation of dynamic 3d array

Tags: c++, arrays, class, 3d

I have made the next class for a 3d array. Declaring a variable as, for example

```
Grid3d n = Grid3d(2,2,2);
n(0,0,0) = 1;
```

works fine, but declaring it as

```
Grid3d n;
n = Grid3d(2,2,2);
n(0,0,0) = 1;
```

Gives me a segmentation fault, the problem seems to be the default constructor, but i don't know how to fix it, any clue?

```
#ifndef _GRID3D_
#define _GRID3D_

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cassert>  // assert()

using namespace std;

class Grid3d
{
private:
    int L;
    int M;
    int N;
    double *** G;

public:
    Grid3d(int,int,int);
    Grid3d();
    Grid3d(const Grid3d &);
    ~Grid3d();

    double & operator()(int,int,int);
};
#endif

//Constructor
Grid3d::Grid3d(int L,int M,int N)
    :L(L), M(M), N(N)
{
    int i,j,k;
    G = new double ** [L];
    for (i=0;i<L;i++){
        G[i] = new double * [M];
        for (j=0;j<M;j++){
            G[i][j] = new double [N];
            for (k=0;k<N;k++){
                G[i][j][k] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

//Constructor vacío
Grid3d::Grid3d()
    :L(0), M(0), N(0)
{
    G = NULL;
}

//Constructor copia
Grid3d::Grid3d(const Grid3d &A)
    :L(A.L), M(A.M), N(A.N)
{
    G = new double ** [L];
    int i,j,k;
    for (i=0;i<L;i++){
        G[i] = new double * [M];
        for (j=0;j<M;i++){
            G[i][j] = new double [N];
            for (k=0;k<N;k++){
                G[i][j][k] = A.G[i][j][k];
            }
        }
    }
}

//Destructor
Grid3d::~Grid3d()
{
    // Libera memoria
    for (int i=0;i<L;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<M;j++){
            delete [] G[i][j];
            G[i][j] = NULL;
        }
        delete [] G[i];
        G[i] = NULL;
    }
    delete G;
    G = NULL;
}

double& Grid3d::operator()(int i,int j,int k)
{
    assert(i >= 0 && i < L);
    assert(j >= 0 && j < M);
    assert(k >= 0 && k < N);
    return G[i][j][k];
}
```

Assignment operator

```
Grid3d Grid3d::operator = (const Grid3d &A)
{
    if (this == &A) {return *this;};
    if (G != NULL){
        // Libera memoria
        for (int i=0;i<L;i++){
            for (int j=0;j<M;j++){
                delete [] G[i][j];
                G[i][j] = NULL;
            }
            delete [] G[i];
            G[i] = NULL;
        }
        delete G;
        G = NULL;
    }

    L = A.L;
    M = A.M;
    N = A.N;
    G = new double ** [L];
    int i,j,k;
    for (i=0;i<L;i++){
        G[i] = new double * [M];
        for (j=0;j<M;i++){
            G[i][j] = new double [N];
            for (k=0;k<N;k++){
                G[i][j][k] = A.G[i][j][k];
            }
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: You are missing an assignment operator.

Comment: Why is your #endif statement halfway through the class definition?

Comment: #endif is there because i have the declaration and implementation of the class in 2 files

Comment: You can store this with a `std::vector<double>` with a size of L*M*N.

Comment: @user1995432 that make sense. just curious.

Comment: @juanchopanza 's answer is *the* answer, btw, (in case that wasn't obvious). There are much better ways to do what you're doing, but his comment is the immediate answer to your problem.

Comment: See this question: [What is the `rule of three`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have dynamically allocated memory, but you have not followed the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29). You are missing an assignment operator, so when you do this:

```
Grid3d n;
n = Grid3d(2,2,2); // both RHS temporary and n point to the same data.
n(0,0,0) = 1;      // Accessing deleted memory: undefined behaviour.
```

you will have two attempted de-allocations of the same memory, because you have `n`'s pointer pointing to the same memory as the temporary used to assign to it in the second line. When the temporary dies, it de-allocated it's memory. When `n` dies, it tries to de-allocate the same memory. Furthermore, any access to that memory after the second line is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Since the destructor sets the inner pointers in G to NULL, it actually goes wrong in the access in operator() - I actually compiled and ran it, just to confirm.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Yeah, I added a comment in the code sample. But even without the access, there would eventually be a double delete.

Comment: I added an assignment operator, but it not working either, i've edited the main post

Comment: @user1995432 sorry, I don't read functions that are more than five lines long. But you could use the [copy and swap idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Copy-and-swap) and leverage the copy constructor.

Answer (score 2):

It's a trivial typo. I'll point out the line, and I'll let you spot where it's gone wrong:

```
for (j=0;j<M;i++)
```

That is, aside from the missing assignment operator, which makes the original constructed object in `n = Grid3d(2,2,2);` be freed, and thus you are accessing `G[i][j][k]` in `operator()` with NULL pointers.

Comment: *totally* worth burning one my my final 3 daily votes for this. did *not* see that coming =P